# (re-arrange)Codeigniter. Where/How should I write the login method if it's on sidebar

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter

beginner question sorry: I have template(just build it from scratch so it's a simple template by html css) that have header, navbar, content,  sidebar,  footer.
but my loginbox  is on the sidebar   and my view files 'footer.php' consist of sidebar and footer. (so my loginbox is on footer.php)
My controller, each method will import the header.php view, somemodule.php(content) view and footer.php view.

**the problem is when I write the login method,  it does not have content view because loginbox is in footer already. no nescessary for somemodule.php(content)view.** (my login form post data to controller login method)

this is my controller

```
 public function login()
{
    $this->load->view('header');

    /// login and validation  algorithm here////
    /// not have $this->load->view('some content') ///

    $this->load->view('footer');  ////my loginform is in footer

}
 public function register()
{
   $this->load->view('header');
   $this->load->view('register_content');   // See? the other methods have a content view
   //// algorithm and validation here /////
   $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

this is my form in the footer view

```
<?php echo form_open('member/login');?>  //post data to method login controller
                    <h2> Login </h2>
                    <ul id='login'>
                        <li>
                            Username:<br>
                            <input type='text' name='username'>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Password:<br>
                            <input type='password' name='password'>
                        </li>
                        <br>
                        <li>
                            <input type='submit' name='btn' value='Log in'>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </form>
```

**When the user input wrong password, I want the website to be on same page with error message  and  the "content view" still be the same.**

or should I write algorithm in Model folder  and import it to controller? but it must import that login model  to all method of controller because all page have footer(loginbox).

Comment: u will get each and everything from CI Manual http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557129/codeigniter-login-system-with-session-to-redirect-user-to-page-if-password-corre one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228121/codeigniter-simple-login-validation-not-working

Comment: in your case: u need to use different button name `<input type='submit' value='Log in' name="login">`

Comment: may be I should move login form to another page  it will easier for me...

Comment: u can, but using different name will resolve

Comment: Could you give some little example?

Comment: Use ajax, do post request using ajax and in login method send response in json format and process it. 



if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {
// Validate Login
return "{'status':'fail','msg':'invalid ID/Password'}";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax, do post request using ajax and in login method send response in json format and process it.

```
    `if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {
    // Validate Login
         return "{'status':'fail','msg':'invalid ID/Password'}";
    }`
```